# Why can't I create labels via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to dynamically create inputs, which will be used to filter products based on color.
At first I tried to create static checkbox-inputs to filter the products. This works. And now I wish to do the same thing again, except this time I wan't to create them dynamically via javascript. Also, instead of plain checkbox-inputs, I have tried to create a label which shows the color, so the user clicks THAT instead of a checkbox.

But for some reason, I cannot create the labels. That is, it creates the first red one, oddly, but not the blue and yellow ones.

I have tried to look at the CSS, the JS-function that creates the inputs and labels, and lots of other things.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $products = $('.grid-products'),
    $variants = $('.grid-variants'),
    $filters = $("#filters input[type='checkbox']"),
    product_filter = new ProductFilterLevel2($products, $variants, $filters);
  product_filter.init();
});

function ProductFilterLevel2(products, variants, filters) {
  var _this = this;

  this.init = function() {
    this.addColorInputs();
    this.filters = $("#filters input[type='checkbox']");


  };
  this.addColorInputs = function() {
    var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'];;
    var filterContainer = document.createElement("div");
    filterContainer.className = "filter-attributes";

    filterContainer.setAttribute("id", "colorFilter");

    for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      var colorInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
      colorInput.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
      colorInput.setAttribute("name", "colour");
      var inputId = "input-" + colors[i];
      colorInput.setAttribute("id", inputId);
      colorInput.setAttribute("value", colors[i]);
      filterContainer.appendChild(colorInput);

      var label = document.createElement("label");
      label.setAttribute("for", inputId);
      var labelColor = document.createElement("div");
      labelColor.setAttribute("id", ("color-" + colors[i]));
      labelColor.className = "color-select";

      label.appendChild(labelColor);
      filterContainer.appendChild(label);

    }
    var mainFilter = document.getElementById("filters");
    mainFilter.append(filterContainer);
  }


  
}
```

```css
#colorFilter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#colorFilter input {
  display: none;
}

#colorFilter label #color-red {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#colorFilter label:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#colorFilter input:checked+label {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#colorFilter .color-select {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#colorFilter label div#color-red {
  background-color: red;
}

#colorFilter label div#color-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#colorFilter label div#color-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div id='filters' class='sections'>
  <div class='filter-attributes'>
    <h4>Static filter - Working</h4>
    <input type='checkbox' name='colour' id='red' value='red'>Red</input>
    <input type='checkbox' name='colour' id='blue' value='blue'>Blue</input>

    <input type='checkbox' name='colour' id='yellow' value='yellow'>Yellow</input>
  </div>
  <h4>Dynamic filter - not working</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Usually, all browsers provide pretty good developer tools

Comment: 1. I made you a snippet. 2. jQUery should run https. 3. You use a really old jQuery version. 4. Why use DOM creation when you have jQuery?

Comment: Please remove all irrelevan code so we have a [mcve]

Comment: @NicoHaase the issue is creating the dynamic labels. It creates the red one, but not the blue or yellow ones. Also, how can developer tool assist me with this?

Comment: Through the developer tools, you can debug the code. Run it line by line, inspect what it does

Comment: "How can developer tools assist with this" - if you look closely, your other elements *are* created - they just have a width of zero! How do you think we would debug this? The same way you would. There's no magic involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only told your red color filter to have any significant width

```
#colorFilter label #color-red {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

The rest inherit `width: 100%` and the parent element has a width of 0 (it's empty, so by default it will have no width!)

By changing the above to the following, all works as I suspect you expected

```
#colorFilter label  {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

Aside: I worked out all of the above by simply examining elements in the chrome dev tools.

Live example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $products = $('.grid-products'),
    $variants = $('.grid-variants'),
    $filters = $("#filters input[type='checkbox']"),
    product_filter = new ProductFilterLevel2($products, $variants, $filters);
  product_filter.init();
});

function ProductFilterLevel2(products, variants, filters) {
  var _this = this;

  this.init = function() {
    this.products = products;
    this.variants = variants;
    this.addColorInputs();
    this.filters = $("#filters input[type='checkbox']");

    this.bindEvents();

  };
  this.addColorInputs = function() {
    var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
    // $("#filters").append("Some appended text.");
    var filterContainer = document.createElement("div");
    filterContainer.className = "filter-attributes";

    filterContainer.setAttribute("id", "colorFilter");

    for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      var colorInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
      colorInput.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
      colorInput.setAttribute("name", "colour");
      var inputId = "input-" + colors[i];
      colorInput.setAttribute("id", inputId);
      colorInput.setAttribute("value", colors[i]);
      filterContainer.appendChild(colorInput);

      var label = document.createElement("label");
      label.setAttribute("for", inputId);
      var labelColor = document.createElement("div");
      labelColor.setAttribute("id", ("color-" + colors[i]));
      labelColor.className = "color-select";

      label.appendChild(labelColor);
      filterContainer.appendChild(label);

    }
    var mainFilter = document.getElementById("filters");
    mainFilter.append(filterContainer);
  }


  this.bindEvents = function() {
    this.filters.click(this.filterGridProducts);
    $('#none').click(this.removeAllFilters);
  };

  this.filterGridProducts = function() {
    //hide all
    _this.products.hide();
    var filteredProducts = _this.variants;
    //filter by colour, size, shape etc
    var filterAttributes = $('.filter-attributes');
    // for each attribute check the corresponding attribute filters selected
    filterAttributes.each(function() {
      var selectedFilters = $(this).find('input:checked');
      // if selected filter by the attribute
      if (selectedFilters.length) {
        var selectedFiltersValues = [];
        selectedFilters.each(function() {
          var currentFilter = $(this);
          selectedFiltersValues.push("[data-" + currentFilter.attr('name') + "='" + currentFilter.val() + "']");
        });
        filteredProducts = filteredProducts.filter(selectedFiltersValues.join(','));
      }
    });
    filteredProducts.parent().show();
  };

  this.removeAllFilters = function() {
    _this.filters.prop('checked', false);
    _this.products.show();
  }
}
```

```css
.sections {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-products {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.grid-products span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}

[data-colour='red'] {
  background: red;
}

[data-colour='yellow'] {
  background: yellow;
}

[data-colour='green'] {
  background: green;
}

[data-colour='blue'] {
  background: blue;
}

.grid-variants {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.large-boxes {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

#colorFilter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#colorFilter input {
  display: none;
}

#colorFilter label {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#colorFilter label:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#colorFilter input:checked+label {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#colorFilter .color-select {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#colorFilter label div#color-red {
  background-color: red;
}

#colorFilter label div#color-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#colorFilter label div#color-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div id='filters' class='sections'>
  <div class='filter-attributes'>
    <h4>Static filter - Working</h4>
    <input type='checkbox' name='colour' id='red' value='red'>Red</input>
    <input type='checkbox' name='colour' id='blue' value='blue'>Blue</input>

    <input type='checkbox' name='colour' id='yellow' value='yellow'>Yellow</input>
  </div>
  <h4>Dynamic filter - not working</h4>
</div>
<div class='sections'>
  <ul>
    <li class='grid-products large-boxes'>
      <h4>Product 1</h4>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='red' data-size='large'>L</div>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='red' data-size='small'>S</div>
    </li>
    <li class='grid-products large-boxes'>
      <h4>Product 2</h4>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='red' data-size='medium'>M</div>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='blue' data-size='small'>S</div>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='green' data-size='large'>L</div>
    </li>
    <li class='grid-products large-boxes'>
      <h4>Product 3</h4>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='yellow' data-size='medium'>M</div>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='blue' data-size='large'>L</div>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='yellow' data-size='large'>L</div>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='green' data-size='medium'>M</div>
    </li>
    <li class='grid-products large-boxes'>
      <h4>Product 4</h4>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='blue' data-size='medium'>M</div>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='blue' data-size='large'>L</div>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='red' data-size='small'>S</div>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='green' data-size='medium'>M</div>
      <div class='grid-variants' data-colour='green' data-size='small'>S</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```